# Error converting data type nvarchar to uniqueidentifier

Tags: python, sql, stored-procedures

I am trying to run a MSSQL procedure from python. Basically my python script just executes a stored procedure named as "my_proc" using this part of code

```
sql_query = """
    use my_db        
    exec dbo.my_proc
"""

res = common.execute_sql(SERVER, USERNAME, PASSWORD, sql_query)
```

The procedure *my_proc* looks like this

```
USE [my_db]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[my_proc] 
AS
BEGIN
  DECLARE @ID NVARCHAR(32) = N'f17584bd-1b19-4847-a9c7-b1560054de69';
  SELECT @ID, CONVERT(uniqueidentifier, @ID);

  EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_start_job @job_id = ID      
END
```

But, when running the script I get the error:

**Error converting data type nvarchar to uniqueidentifier**

So, it looks like the part below *BEGIN* where the conversion from nvarchar to uniquetradeidentifer happens, fails.

I also tried

```
DECLARE @ID uniqueidentifier
SET @ID = CAST( 'f17584bd-1b19-4847-a9c7-b1560054de69' as uniqueidentifier )
```

but with same error.

What is wrong here?

Initially I had

```
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_start_job @job_id = 'f17584bd-1b19-4847-a9c7-b1560054de69'
```

which works when executing the procedure on sql level, but when running that procedure using my python script I got the error:

**The specified @job_id ('F17584BD-1B19-4847-A9C7-B1560054DE69') does not exist**

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1):

I tried your SQL Code in SSMS.
It is not possible because you use @ID NVARCHAR(32) but the string length is longer. Use @ID NVARCHAR(36) instead.